# Aggregation of values in DataFrame in Python Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have DataFrame with contracts like below:

```
df = pd.DataFrame ({"ID" : ["1", "2", "1", "2"], 
                    "currency" : ["USD", "USD", "EUR", "CHF"],
                     "amount" : [100, 200, 400, 500]})
```

And I need to calculate:

1. (col1) Number of contracts with EUR currency
2. (col2) Number of contracts with currency other than EUR
3. (col3) Amount of contracts on EUR
   4/ (col4) Amount of contract with currency other than EUR

To be more precision, I need as a result DataFrame like below:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.assign`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html) for new columns (lambda is used for working with new columns counted before in `assign`) with aggregate `sum`:

```
cols = ['col1','col2','col3','col4']
df = (df.assign(col1 = df.currency == 'EUR',
                col2 = df.currency != 'EUR',
                col3 = lambda x: df.amount.mask(x.col2, 0),
                col4 = lambda x: df.amount.mask(x.col1, 0))
        .groupby(df['ID'])[cols]
        .sum()
        .reset_index())
print (df)
  ID  col1  col2  col3  col4
0  1     1     1   400   100
1  2     0     2     0   700
```